# Accordion Panel open by default - how to change it

Tags: javascript, accordion

I found this fiddle https://codepen.io/LewisBriffa/pen/qjwqLb and it is great! My problem, is that I cant get the second panel to be closed by default on pageload.

I tried to add this:

```
       <script>
       $( function() {
       $( ".accordion" ).accordion( { active: false, collapsible: true } 
       );
       } );
       </script>
```

But still it doesn't work

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand why Panel 2 is opened.

it's the ".active" class (like you already tried working with in your example)

So the simplest option is to just leave the class "active" out of the default class list of panel 2.

so you turn:

```
 <div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item active">
```

into

```
 <div class="accordion__item js-accordion-item">
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I'll be damned - IT WORKED! Thank you mister!

Comment: as I said, for things like this, especially if it's not your own code, try to go back and see what causes a panel to be "open". In case you want to remove classes in the future with jquery you can use [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now. I looked in the wrong place and messed with the js all the time, but should've looked in the html.